# Laravel Mass Assignment without id( autoincrement)

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, upsert

would like to know if it's possible to insert or upsert in Laravel by keeping the Autoincrement id blank.
here is my table migration

```
 $table->id(); // Autoincrement
 $table->string("description");
 $table->string("part_number");
 $table->string("serial_number");
 $table->smallInteger("qty");
```

here is the data that I would like to upsert. when I try to the upsert with `$data1`, I get an error. haven't tried `$data2` yet but that is one more possibility.

> 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1

```
$data1= [
            [
              id=>"",
              description=>"xyz",
              part_number=>"xyz",
              serial_number=>"xyz",
              qty=>1
            ],
            [
              id=>"",
              description=>"xyz1",
              part_number=>"xyz1",
              serial_number=>"xyz1",
              qty=>1
            ],
            [
              id=>"",
              description=>"xyz2",
              part_number=>"xyz2",
              serial_number=>"xyz2",
              qty=>1
            ],
           
        ];

 
 $data2=[
            [
              id=>1,
              description=>"xyz",
              part_number=>"xyz",
              serial_number=>"xyz",
              qty=>1
            ],
            [
              id=>2,
              description=>"xyz1",
              part_number=>"xyz1",
              serial_number=>"xyz1",
              qty=>1
            ],
            [
              id=>"",
              description=>"xyz2",
              part_number=>"xyz2",
              serial_number=>"xyz2",
              qty=>1
            ],
           
        ]
```

Comment: what logic are you using for the upsert? `saveMany`?

Comment: `Model::upsert($data,["id","part_number"])`. that's it. not doing anything else. have left all the fields unguarded

Comment: It seems a bit weird to me that you want to store rows on database with no id. However, make the id nullable on the database level. $table->id()->nullable(); refresh your migrations and when adding data 'id' => null

Comment: No, I don't want to store it without id. I think mySql basic INSERT INTO does it automatically, If no id is specified, it generates id automatically. was expecting similar behavior here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Might be helpful if someone else runs into same issue or wants similar results.

Laravel didn't disappoint finally. It allows blank autoincrement fields and does the incrementing by itself( native DB function I think, in my case it's MySQl).
Just have to set `'strict' => false`  in `config/database.php`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mention id in your data1 array. Laravel will handle it automatically. As you mentioned id as " ", Laravel is trying to store it like that and id is unsigned integer column so you are getting the error " 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1"

Try the below data array it should work:

```
$data1 = [
            [
              description=>"xyz",
              part_number=>"xyz",
              serial_number=>"xyz",
              qty=>1
            ],
            [
              description=>"xyz1",
              part_number=>"xyz1",
              serial_number=>"xyz1",
              qty=>1
            ],
            [
              description=>"xyz2",
              part_number=>"xyz2",
              serial_number=>"xyz2",
              qty=>1
            ],           
        ];
```